# How can I resolve this error I keep getting in my VBA Code?

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA and this is the first Macro I've tried to write.

I have an excel table which has five columns titled Address, location , works , action and completed. I want to create a new worksheet for each unique address and then copy the relevant rows for that address on that new worksheet. However, I only want to copy and paste the unique rows if the value in "Completed" is "N". The Value in completed can only be "Y" or "N".

Here is the code I have written:

```
Dim AddressField As Range
Dim AddressName As Range
Dim CompletedField As Range
Dim NewWSheet As Worksheet
Dim WSheet As Worksheet
Dim WSheetFound As Boolean
Dim DataWSheet As Worksheet

Set DataWSheet = Worksheets("Data")
Set AddressField = DataWSheet.Range("A4", DataWSheet.Range("A4").End(xlDown))
Set CompletedField = DataWSheet.Range("E4", DataWSheet.Range("E4").End(xlDown))


Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For Each AddressName In AddressField

             For Each WSheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
                  If CompletedField = "No" Then
                  If WSheet.Name = AddressName Then
                  WSheetFound = True
                Exit For 
                Else
                WSheetFound = False ' if it doesn't assign False to the WSheetFound variable
            End If
        Next WSheet
    
    
    If WSheetFound Then 'if WSheetFound = True
    
       
        AddressName.Offset(0, 0).Resize(1, 5).Copy Destination:=Worksheets(AddressName.Value).Range("A3").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
    
        Else 'if WSheetFound = False
        
        Set NewWSheet = Sheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)) 
        NewWSheet.Name = AddressName 
        DataWSheet.Range("A3", DataWSheet.Range("A3").End(xlToRight)).Copy Destination:=NewWSheet.Range("A3") 
        
        AddressName.Offset(0, 0).Resize(1, 5).Copy Destination:=NewWSheet.Range("A4") 
        
    End If

    Next AddressName

    For Each WSheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

        WSheet.UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit

    Next WSheet

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub
```

I keep getting the "Next without For" error when I try to run the code. I think it has something to do with the "IF CompletedField = "N" line, but not sure how to fix it !

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You are missing an `End If`  before `Next wSheet` in that first loop.

Comment: I've added in an "End If" directly below the first one and now im getting a mismatch error and it says the error is on the line " If CompletedField = "N"

Comment: I think you want `If AddressName.Offset(,4).Value = "No" Then`. Refer to the cell 4 columns to the right of `AddressName` using `Offset`.

Comment: Side note: `AddressName.Offset(0, 0).Resize(1, 5)` - the `.Offset(0,0)` is redundant and can be removed.

Comment: Hi ben do I need to include this below the "For Each WSheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets" line?

Comment: Yes, replace `If CompletedField = "No" Then` with `If AddressName.Offset(,4).Value = "No" Then`.

Comment: Now I'm getting " next before for" again

Comment: OK, not getting the " next before for" anymore I'm getting " that name is already taken try again" error

Comment: Now its getting stuck on the NewWSheet.Name = AddressName line saying i should use a new name

Comment: You can't use the same name as an existing sheet

Comment: @TimWilliams it was working fine before I tried to add this new condition of only copying the "N"s

Comment: When `CompletedField`  is "Yes" then `WSheetFound = False` and you are creating a sheet when one is not required.

Comment: If you use https://rubberduckvba.com/ to indent your code the nesting level errors will become obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```vb
Sub CopyRows()

    Dim c As Range, ws As Worksheet, DataWSheet As Worksheet, wb As Workbook
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set DataWSheet = wb.Worksheets("Data")
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    For Each c In DataWSheet.Range("A4", DataWSheet.Range("A4").End(xlDown)).Cells
        
        If c.EntireRow.Columns("E").Value = "No" Then
            Set ws = Nothing
            On Error Resume Next            'ignore any error on next line
            Set ws = wb.Worksheets(c.Value) 'try to get the sheet
            On Error GoTo 0                 'stop ignoring errors
            If ws Is Nothing Then           'was sheet found?
                Set ws = wb.Worksheets.Add(after:=wb.Worksheets(wb.Worksheets.Count))
                DataWSheet.Rows(3).Copy ws.Range("A3")  'copy headers
                ws.Name = c.Value                       'name the sheet
            End If
            c.Resize(1, 5).Copy ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        End If
        
    Next c
    
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        ws.UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit
    Next ws
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for this.When I try to run nothing happens, go into the code and Sub CopyRows() is just in yellow. Kept messing with it and managed to get it to run it said "subscript out of range" now its gone back to not running at all all ive done is open and close my excel

Comment: ignore that last comment I've solved that part. It says "subscript out of range" on this line: Set DataWSheet = wb.Worksheets("Data")

Comment: Is the "Data" sheet in ThisWorkbook, or some other workbook (ActiveWorkbook?)

Comment: @ Tim Williams - the data sheet is in this workbook. There's only one workbook and only one worksheet (initally - before the new ones are made), and that worksheet is called "Data"

Comment: ThisWorkbook is the workbook where the code is running - if you’re getting that error it’s telling you there’s no sheet with that name

Comment: so am I supposed to call the worksheet "Data" or something else? I'm confused but thank you for your replies

Comment: If the name on the tab is Data then it should work

Comment: I've called it "Data" but when I run it absolutely nothing happens, like even if i press run macro, nothing happens at all

Comment: You say nothing happens - not even any error now? What changed? Have you tried putting breakpoints in the code to see where it reaches?

Answer (score 0):

Check the Completed column before deciding if a sheet needs to be created or not.

Update - Added copy for A1,A2,D2

```vb
Sub test()

    Dim AddressField As Range, AddressName As Range, CompletedField As Range
    Dim NewWSheet As Worksheet, WSheet As Worksheet, DataWSheet As Worksheet
    Dim WSheetFound As Boolean
    
    Set DataWSheet = Worksheets("Data")
    Set AddressField = DataWSheet.Range("A4", DataWSheet.Range("A4").End(xlDown))
    'Set CompletedField = DataWSheet.Range("E4", DataWSheet.Range("E4").End(xlDown))
     
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    For Each AddressName In AddressField
          
        If AddressName.Cells(1, 5) = "No" Then ' col E
            
            For Each WSheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
            
                If WSheet.Name = AddressName.Value2 Then
                    WSheetFound = True
                    Exit For
                Else
                    WSheetFound = False ' if it doesn't assign False to the WSheetFound variable
                End If
            
            Next WSheet
        
            If WSheetFound Then 'if WSheetFound = True
                AddressName.Offset(0, 0).Resize(1, 5).Copy _
                   Destination:=Worksheets(AddressName.Value).Range("A3").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
            Else 'if WSheetFound = False
            
                Set NewWSheet = Sheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
                NewWSheet.Name = AddressName
                DataWSheet.Range("A1:A2").Copy NewWSheet.Range("A1")
                DataWSheet.Range("D2").Copy NewWSheet.Range("D2")
                DataWSheet.Range("A3", DataWSheet.Range("A3").End(xlToRight)).Copy _
                    Destination:=NewWSheet.Range("A3")
                
                AddressName.Offset(0, 0).Resize(1, 5).Copy Destination:=NewWSheet.Range("A4")
            
             End If
        End If
    
    Next AddressName
    
    For Each WSheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        WSheet.UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit
    Next WSheet
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Trying to use this, when i go to run my macro sometimes nothing happens at all and sometimes it gets stuck on the "Sub test()" line. Can you help me resolve this?

Comment: managed to get it going but now it says "subscript out of range" - was i supposed to leave your comments in or remove the comment

Comment: @Jbird100 the comments make no difference to way the code operates.Change `Worksheets("Data")` to `Worksheets(1)`

Comment: Thank you for your response. Keeps getting stuck on "Sub test()"

Comment: @Jbird100 How are you calling the sub, from the editor window ? Is column E "Y" or "N", your code has `If CompletedField = "No" `. Is this the same problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68982276/could-someone-assist-me-with-a-problem-i-have-in-vba

Comment: omg it works!! forgot to change the No to N! Thank you very much for your help, it's greatly appreciated :) You've really helped me out there

Comment: so this works great. Just need a minor addition to it. I've got some text in cells A1, A2, and D2 which need to be copy and pasted to all the new sheets. Do you know how I could add this in?

Comment: @JBird see update, 2 new lines after `NewWSheet.Name = AddressName`

Comment: Thank you for all your help. This is working how I needed it to :)